# Postgres Self Join query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

The db schema along with sample data is something like this -

Country table

```
| Country | Country Code | 
--------------------------
    ABC         AE 
    BCD         RW
```

Dest Table

```
| DestCountry Code | DestCurrency Code | totalDestAmount |
----------------------------------------------------------
      RW                  USD                  3600
      RW                  USD                  13000
      AE                  RWF                  8880
      AE                  USD                  0
```

Src Table

```
    | SrcCountry Code | SrcCurrency Code | totalSrcAmount |
   ---------------------------------------------------------
              AE                 USD              7
              RW                 RWF             10
              AE                 AED             399
              AE                 USD              0
```

I want the output to be like this -

```
 | Mapping | SrcAmount| DestAmount | Currency |
 -----------------------------------------------
    ABC-BCD      7         0         USD
    BCD-ABC     10        13000      RWF
    ABC-BCD     399       8880       AED
    BCD-ABC      0        3600       USD
```

Each country mapping should have the individual incoming and outgoing currencies. For ex - when talking about ABC-BCD,  the **SrcAmount** refers to the amount in ABC src going to BCD for a particular currency. The **DestAmount** refers to the amount coming in to ABC from BCD (again for a particular currency).

Comment: How may we help you actually?

Comment: I am unable to get the proper result.

Comment: And your improper query looks how?